# how to postback and show a div on hover and get information from the database

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, hover, postback

I use ASP.NET, and would like to list a set of results in a table. The table will have output a link of people's name which are generated from the database. What I would like is when you hover over the link, then it would display a small div which will populate a few results which is generated from the database. What methods and tecnhiques can I use to postback on hover, and retrieve info from a ASP.net function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery ajax for this: It is a very good way to handle browser requests dynamically with server side code.

```
jQuery('#link_element_id').hover(function(){
       $.ajax({
              type: "POST or GET",
              url:    "url",
              datatype:"json or xml", // check more option
              success: function(data) {
                       // handle response data
                         jQuery('#div_id').show();
                       },
              async:   true
            });    

});
```

For more details check these links:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Answer (score 1):

You could look into using jquery's [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) function and calling a webmethod that returns json data or even html that you could then use to load into your div and then display on hover.